# How can i filter array on object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array named `files`:

```
        files = [
            {
                id: "1", 
                title: "aras", 
                price: 100, 
                size: 25, 
                tools: [
                    "Hammer",
                    "Zip",
                    "Line",
                    "Nexti"
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: "2", 
                title: "yasio", 
                price: 150, 
                size: 30, 
                tools: [
                    "Hammer",
                    "Zip",
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: "3", 
                title: "janio", 
                price: 200, 
                size: 30, 
                tools: [
                    "Line",
                    "Nexti"
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: "4", 
                title: "chashio", 
                price: 400, 
                size: 35, 
                tools: [
                    "Nexti"
                    ]
            },



          ]
```

I want to filter this object, for example, to get the array:  prices between `90` to `150` and sizes between `25` to `40` and tools to include `Hammer` and `Zip`.
output must be:

```
{id: "1", title: "aras", price: 100, size: 25,tools:[...]},
{id: "2", title: "aras", price: 150, size: 30,tools:[...]},
{id: "4", title: "aras", price: 90,  size: 40,tools:[...]},
```

**How can i do it?**

Answer (score 1):

```
files.filter(function(file){
            return ((file.price>= 90 && file.price<=150) && (file.size >= 25 && file.size <= 40))
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return items which satisfies the following condition:

```
(price>=90 && price <= 150) && (size >= 25 && size <= 40)
```

```js
var files = [
  {id: "1", title: "aras", price: 100, size: 25, tools: ["Hammer","Zip","Line","Nexti"] },
  {id: "2", title: "aras", price: 150, size: 30, tools: ["Hammer","Zip"]},
  {id: "3", title: "aras", price: 160, size: 35, tools: ["Line","Nexti"]},
  {id: "4", title: "aras", price: 90,  size: 40, tools: ["Nexti"]},
  {id: "5", title: "aras", price: 200, size: 45, tools: []}
]

var res = files.filter(f => (f.price>=90 && f.price <= 150) 
                         && (f.size >= 25 && f.size <= 40) 
                         && (f.tools.includes('Hammer') &&  f.tools.includes('Zip')));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, my problem is here, I can't filter by tools in my files. do you have some idea for it?

Comment: @Aras, `filter()` is a native JavaScript array method...I don't know why you can't use that!

Comment: I use it I want to check some object in my arras list something like includes methods

Comment: @Aras, do you want both *Hammer* and *Zip* to be present in the *tools*?....updated the answer with `includes`.......please check.